Google Sheet formula to search in a string from a list
I'm working on Google spreadsheet with key phrases, strings of text, in column A. I want to search column A based on a list of keywords that live in another sheet (makes tab). When a keyword matches a word in a string in column A, I want to print that word in an adjacent cell to column A.
Please find the spreadsheet below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O0dd0MGh9x4lLX7LWbLXVX18nor1oVO8Dqf3X9Hz_sY/edit?usp=sharing


You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(regexextract(Σ,"(?i)"&textjoin("|",1,makes!A2:A))))))


